# Is there a way to create a PDF larger than 10 MB

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript, filesize

Running ghostscript to create a PDF larger than 10 MB fails.  I ensured I upgraded to the latest ghostscript. Is this a hard limit or is there a way that ghostscript can allow file sizes larger than 10 MB

Comment: There is no such limit. There is also nothing in Ghostscript called 'ghostwriter'.

Comment: My bad for the typo which is fixed.  However I have reproduced multiple times the failure to create a PDF as around 10 MB yet ones smaller than that are created without a problem.  So something seems to be happening based on size.  Do you have any ideas what size related issues there could be.

Comment: No. If you think you have found a bug I suggest you open a bug report. don't forget to include the input file and command line used. I regularly create PDF files in excess of 10MB and have created files in excess of 4GB (to test large file support). Note you still have a reference to 'ghostwriter' in there, but it's not important.

Comment: I tend to assume its not a bug but something I can fix on my system.  If it works for other people and not myself it means there is something I don't know about configuring it that is my problem.

The commands to run are pretty basic 

gs -q  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sOutputFile=' . $output . ' ' . $files

I have played with the compatibility level going to 1.7

Comment: The compatibilityLevel makes little difference to anything, and (IIRC) currently defaults to 2.0 anyway. The main difference is 1.4 and above or less than 1.4 which determines whether transparent pages are rendered or preserved. While it's possible you are tripping over a limit, it certainly isn't a simple 10MB limit on file size. Without seeing the input file I can't offer any help.